# how to setup a debugger for AEM or CQ?

Tags: eclipse, maven, aem

how to setup a debugger for AEM or CQ? I'm using Eclipse IDE and Maven 3.2.5 for build and AEM version 6.0. I'm new to AEM and Java.

Answer (score 2):

This Adobe article walks you through it: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html

> Step 1: Add the Remote Debugging JVM Parameter
>
> ```
> To use remote debugging, you must start CQ5 with this JVM parameter:
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
> ```
>
> You can add the parameter by doing the following;
>
> ```
> Start your server like this: crx-quickstart/bin/start -d --debug-port 8000. The -d parameter adds the jvm parameter to the CQ5 java process.
> Add it to your crx-quickstart/bin/start script CQ_JVM_OPTS environment variable (so your server always starts in debug mode).
> Include it as a parameter when starting CQ5 with java -jar directly. For example, java -Xmx512m
> ```
>
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -jar cq-author-4502.jar
>
> Notes
>
> ```
> If necessary, you can change the port defined under "...,address=8000,..." from 8000 to something that works better in
> ```
>
> your environment.
>       Starting CQ 5.5, using the last solution, when Quickstart forks a new process it does not start the JVM with the debug options. You can
>   prevent forking by specifying the -nofork command line option.
>       Te start script is located under crx-quickstart/server for CQ versions < 5.5
>
> Step 2: Start a remote debugging session
>
> To start a remote debugging session from Eclipse, do the following:
>
> ```
> Open Eclipse.
> Choose Run > Debug Configurations.
> Right-click Remote Java Applications and select New.
> Select your CQ5 project under Project.
> Type in the port from the "address" configuration of the jvm parameter defined above. In the example, it is port 8000 (and the host
> ```
>
> name of the machine you are connecting to, most likely localhost)
>       To start a debugging session, double-click your new configuration in the Debug Configurations screen after saving it.
>
> Applies to:  CQ 5.x and Adobe Experience Manager 6.x

Answer (score 2):

If you're on windows follow these steps.

Open AEM crx-quickstart, move onto bin, open start.bat(Right click and edit), find default JVM options, add the line 
`-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=3000` next to headless=true in the start.bat file, save it. Open cmd in the bin folder. Type start.bat and hit enter which will open the instance with debugging port 3000.

Open Eclipse. Add breakpoints to the java file. Run > Debug Configurations > Remote Java Application, right click and select New Configuration, provide a name, select project(the one with .core), change port to 3000, apply and debug. Change the perspective to Debug, Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other > Debug.

Open AEM Page containing the component which uses the java class for which the breakpoints have added. If you’ve added breakpoints for the HelloWorldModel.java, open the page with helloworld component or refresh if already opened. And that’s it, eclipse will notify and the program will be paused at the breakpoint.

**Possible Errors you might encounter with:**

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection
>   refused: connect

The debugger has already started when you hit apply and debug and trying to run the debugger again will get you this error.

> Debugger not pausing at breakpoints and no notification in eclipse.

If the instance was already running and you hit start.bat in cmd, you’ll find this unusuality. Close the instance, and enter start.bat(in the bin folder). You’ll find the message below when the instance is ready. It might or might won’t open the browser by its own. So just open the browser and enter http://localhost:[portnumber]/.

```
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from ‘/ (root)’ using class loader for DefaultSecurityConfiguration class!
RAWProcessor succesfully installed
17.10.2019 12:59:41.437 *INFO * [main] Startup completed
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Start AEM service in debug mode with -debug parameter and a port number.

**Step2:** Setup debug configuration in IDE with the above port.

***References***:

[How to start AEM in debug mode?](https://rashidjorvee.blogspot.com/2018/12/how-to-start-aem-in-debug-mode.html)

[CQ5How To Setup Remote Debugging With Eclipse](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html)